# Delete Worksheet from Access 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form that exports and edits excel files for users. I have an issue when trying to have my code delete an existing worksheet from my Access 2010 VBA code.

My Code:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Document.xlsx")

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
  If sht.Name = "DeleteSheet" Then
    wb.Worksheets("DeleteSheet").Delete
  End If
Next sht

wb.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit

End Sub
```

When I run the code, there is no error. However, the sheet does not get deleted. I know that sht.Name does read the sheet name "DeleteSheet", allowing the `if` statement to run. So, I believe it comes down to either the saving method or this line: `wb.Worksheets("DeleteSheet").Delete`. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete the worksheet directly, i.e.

Instead of

wb.Worksheets("DeleteSheet").Delete

Use

sht.Delete

Comment: `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: Your edit doesn't cause the error, but the sheet still doesn't get removed :/ thanks for the attempt!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this, Ryan?

```
Dim xl As Object
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=False
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Document.xlsx")

For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
  If sht.Name = "DeleteSheet" Then
    wb.Worksheets("DeleteSheet").Select
    xl.ActiveSheet.Delete
  End If
Next sht

wb.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Comment: This time I get a dialogue box which asks me if I want to overwrite the current excel file in that location. I clicked `Yes`, however the worksheet is still in the document.

Comment: It is reading the sheet names correctly, I just don't see it deleting anything. This is rather frustrating haha. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You may want to check that you don't have any orphaned Excel session running in Task Manager that could still be locking the file. I just checked the code above and it works. I know this stuff can be frustrating!! :-). I edited the code a little since you may have first copied it.

Comment: Sadly I don't see anything. I think I'm just going to work around this by making a macro in excel that deletes the worksheet, then just call the macro from Access. Not necessarily the best way of doing it, but for now it will do. Thanks DanielG!